# Eloquent multiple nested relations with constraint

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Trying to get data from multiple nested relationship with a where constraint:

Model User:

```
    <?php

    use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;
    use Zizaco\Entrust\HasRole;

  class User extends BaseModel implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
  use HasRole;

protected $fillable = array('username', 'password');
/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password');
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
protected $softDelete = true;  

 public function editor()
{
    return $this->hasOne('User_Editor', 'user_id');
}
?>
```

Model User_Editor:

```
   <?php

   class User_Editor extends BaseModel {
/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users_editors';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array();

/**
 * Defiens the column names of fillable columns.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = array();

/**
 * Relationships
 */
public function credentials()
{
    return $this->hasMany('User_Editor_Credential', 'user_editor_id');
}

public function specialties()
{
    return $this->hasMany('User_Editor_Specialty', 'user_editor_id');
}
?>
```

Model User_Editor_Credentials:

```
    <?php

 class User_Editor_Credential extends BaseModel {
/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users_editors_credentials';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array();

/**
 * Defiens the column names of fillable columns.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = array();
 }
```

Model User_Editor_Specialties:

```
    <?php

     class User_Editor_Specialty extends BaseModel {
/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users_editors_specialties';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array();

/**
 * Defiens the column names of fillable columns.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = array();
 }
```

**Return**

select * from User, User_Editor, User_Editor_Credentials, User_Editor_Specialty where User_Editor_Specialty.specialty In (array).

**So far I've tried,**

```
    $this->data['editors'] = User::with(['editor.credentials.specialties' => function($q) use($data){
            $q->whereIn('specialty',$data);
        }])
        ->get();
```

But this throws an error call to undefined method specialties. Please guide, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To those who might have suffered for long trying to find a way to work around nested relationships, and also, if you are writing a join condition with whereIn (which throws call to undefined method because of a bug in the Laravel), Please find below ans,

```
    $editors = User::with(['editor.credentials','editor.specialties']);
    $this->data['editors'] = $editors->whereHas('editor', function($q) use ($a_data){
       $q->whereHas('specialties',function($sq) use($a_data){
            $sq->whereIn('specialty',$a_data);
       });
    })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update: the PR has been just merged to 4.2, so now it's possible to use *dot nested* notation in `has` methods ( `->has('relation1.relation2)` `->whereHas('relation1.relation2, ..`  )**

Your dot notated relations must be logically chained:

```
`with(['editor.credentials', ' editor.specialties' => function ....
```

You tried to search for the `specialties` relation on the `User_Editor_Credential` model.

---

According to the comments:

```
User::with(['editor.credentials','editor.specialties'])
    ->whereHas('editor' => function($q) use ($data){
       $q->whereHas('specialties' => function($q) use ($data){
          $q->whereIn('specialty',$data);
       });
    })->get();
```

or if you use my PR https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4954

```
User::with(['editor.credentials','editor.specialties'])
    ->whereHas('editor.specialties' => function($q) use ($data){
        $q->whereIn('specialty',$data);
    })->get();
```

It will return all the `users` that have related editor.specialties matching `whereIn`, with related `editor` and all its related `credentials` and `specialties` (the latter won't be filtered)

Comment: Thanks that worked. But it gives all the users and doesn't seems to take into account the where condition. I tried running the query. It does select * on users table. I think has() might give me the desired result, but not sure how to work around with has() for multiple nested relations with where clause.

Comment: then what exactly you want to filter with that `where` clause and what you want to return ?

Comment: I need to get all the data from users table, editors table, credentials table if specialty from specialties table matches one of the values from $data array. So say, Users has id=1 username='admin' and id=2 username ='testeditor', Users_Editor has id=1 user_id(FK)=2 self_description="some stuff", User_Editor_Credentials has id=1 user_editor_id=1(FK) credential="testcredentials" and User_Editor_Specialties has id=1 user_editor_id=1(FK) specialty="Books". So, I want to get All the data from all the tables if specialty = "Books" eg. And the filtered result will be details related to "testeditor"

Comment: whereHas() doesn't work with dot notation. I will need to use joins, but again if I use join as I use whereIn() clause with join, it throws Call to undefined method JoinClause::whereIn()

Comment: You are right, but there's my PR on the laravel repo that allows dot nested in `whereHas`: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4954. In the meantime I add the code how to do that.

Comment: thanks so much for that. I did solve it finally. Let me update the question and ans too